# get text from page and put it into a variable

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-access-token

I want to extend a facebook access token using the method below:

```js
function extend(fb_access_token) {
 var extendingUrl;
  
 try{
  console.log("Extending Facebook Access Token.");
  
  if (app_id == "" || app_id == null) {
   alert("App ID not configured properly.");
   hasError = true;
   return;
  } else {
   hasError = false;
  }
  
  if (app_secret == "" || app_secret == null) {
   alert("App Secret not configured properly.");
   hasError = true;
   return;
  } else {
   hasError = false;
  }

  if (fb_access_token == "" || fb_access_token == null) {
   alert("Facebook Access Token not was not generated.");
   hasError = true;
   return;
  } else {
   hasError = false;
  }
  
  if(hasError) {
   alert("URL not formed.");
  } else {
   extendingUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+app_id+"&client_secret="+app_secret+"&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+fb_access_token;
   window.location.replace = extendingUrl;
   console.log("Facebook Access Token successfully extended.");
  }
  
 } catch (OAuthException) {
  console.log("Login status or access token has expired, been revoked, or is otherwise invalid.");
 }
}
```

I want to get the generated access token from the page that will eventually give the extended access token, see `var extendingUrl`.

The page will return something like:

```
access_token=CAAERkjuisOYBALHbBZB9oq01ybCoyBfyGlSHtkkZBDqDvevrWZC42JwMawxxxOxQsiKHMNVPHZCbh3ntF7GdnYwnq3BLTh6ZA2YUJCVSh8QA5nEZACZCXVtZCL5RZC72pl3afKMAOMG2WGKtjnD1GJTjQEPC2XH3X1ycr3GeAUWBShDj7ojFVCWhDe6jBGvBu2nn7Ohu9C2udBoamOBxoQFun&expires=5182005
```

and I will substring the string above and eliminate `access_token=` and `&expires=5182005` to a new variable, and store it into my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I used jquery and fed the url (extendingUrl), in return, it gave me the contents of the url I requested. Then I used regex and substring to eliminate the unwanted text.

```js
$.get(extendingUrl, function(data) {
  var raw = data;
  var patt1 = /(access_token=)(.*)(?=&expires=)/;
  var result = raw.match(patt1);
  var longToken = result[0].substring(13, 400);
});
```